# Changing innerHTML based on input value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="input" type="text" name="input" value="Enter Here">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <div id="display">
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
input = document.getElementById("input");
if (input.value == "Hello") {
  display.innerHTML = "Hello";
} else {
  display.innerHTML = "Type";
}
```

When I change the input value by clicking on the input field and typing "*Hello*", it does not display "*Hello*" in **display.innerHTML**. I would like it to display "*Hello*" when "*Hello*" is typed into the input field. That's a lot of "*Hello*"'s! Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `display= document.getElementById("display");`?

Comment: When are you running this JavaScript? On page load? Then it will run before the user has a chance to type anything, but never again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
  display=document.getElementById("display");
input.oninput=function(){
  if (input.value === "Hello") {
  display.innerHTML = "Hello";
} else {
  display.innerHTML = "Type";
}
};
```

```html
    <input id="input" type="text" name="input" value="Enter Here">
  <div id="display">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code only gets executed once before you have entered anything in the input field.

You need to either setup a `change` handler for the input field or a `submit` handler for the form and set `display.innerHTML`.

Also, did you miss a `display = document.getElementById("display");`?

Answer (score 0):

*If you want use your button for submit the value of your textbox (your input type text-field)* use onclick event as follows:

```js
function displayData() {
  var div_display = document.getElementById('display');
  /* This is your input, but you shoud use another Id for your fields. */
  var textValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
  

  /* Change the inner HTML of your div. */
  div_display.innerHTML = textValue;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" name="input" value="Enter Here" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayData();" />

<div id="display">
</div>
```

Hope it helps.